# How do I expand a background-color of a html element?

Tags: html, css, html-table

1st image is what I have achieved. The list of time there is an `th` of a table.

2nd image is what I am trying to achieve. It would be easy if I set directly the `td` background-color. But the problem is the td colspan below are dynamic based on the settings. So there could be like 1 `td` has colspan='3' and the other `td` has colspan='7'.

Is there any way that I can expand the background-color on the `th` to achieve just like the 2nd image?

Sample code: https://jsfiddle.net/earlquartz47/ydn0wxfu/15/

(1st image)
[image]

(2nd image)

[image]

I tried to increase the padding-bottom to increase the height of the background-color. How do I keep the `tr` and `td` on the same spot? Is there any css property I need to set?

[image]

Below is what the dynamic colspan of td are represented.
[image]

### Edited to show the code

```html
<table>
<tr >
  <th class="rows-table">4am</th>
  <th class="rows-table">5am</th>
  <th class="rows-table">6am</th>
  <th class="rows-table" style="background-color:gray">7am</th>
  <th class="rows-table" style="background-color:gray">8am</th>
  <th class="rows-table" style="background-color:gray">9am</th>
  <th class="rows-table">10am</th>
  <th class="rows-table">11am</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="rows-table" colspan="4">TEST</td>
  <td class="rows-table">TEST</td>
  <td class="rows-table" >TEST</td>
  <td class="rows-table" >TEST</td>
  <td class="rows-table" >TEST</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="rows-table">TEST</td>
  <td class="rows-table">TEST</td>
  <td class="rows-table" colspan="5">TEST</td>
  <td class="rows-table" >TEST</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="padding:10px;background-color:gainsboro" colspan="2">TEST</td>
  <td style="padding:10px;background-color:gainsboro" >TEST</td>
  <td style="padding:10px;background-color:gainsboro" >TEST</td>
  <td style="padding:10px;background-color:gainsboro" colspan="4">TEST</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

```css
.rows-table{
  padding:10px;background-color:gainsboro
}
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: You can try a combination of `border-right: var(--extra-width) solid var(--background-color);`, `border-left: var(--extra-width) solid var(--background-color);` with the same color as your background color and width as needed, and then `margin-right: calc(-1 * var(--extra-width));`, `margin-left: calc(-1 * var(--extra-width));`

Comment: ^ putting as comment because its from top of my head and i don't have time to test that right now

Comment: What exactly do you mean by expand a background colour? And how does this relate to your images? You can expand a th or a td by adding padding.

Comment: Hi @SteveTomlin I edited my post. I tried to increase the padding-bottom to increase the height. But how do I retain the tr and td to it's the same position? See updated post.

Comment: Your second image has a grey bg not online with the numbers. Why?

Comment: Oh I see. Your question needs correction. You mean how do you achieve the third image. The answer is don't do it on the th. Apply the style to every nth td element

Comment: Yes but my problem is the colspan of the td are dynamic. So basically if I do it on the td element it will be mess up. 1 td can have 3 colspan and the other might be 5 or 7. @SteveTomlin

Comment: Doesn't matter. You can't just overlay a th over a td. Show your code and maybe you may get better help

Comment: Hi @SteveTomlin I have updated my post to show how dynamic colspan of td are presented. It's hard to show a code. It's written in Angular and lots of conditions that is not related to the question.

Comment: @SteveTomlin how do I overlay a th over a td?

Comment: @AnthonyCuartero - we don't need more photos, we need to see the code you are working with. Edit your question to include the HTML/CSS for your table - not an image of your code, but the code pasted into the question (using the `<>` stack snippet tool preferably). You're more likely to get the help you need.

Comment: Hi @SteveTomlin https://jsfiddle.net/earlquartz47/ydn0wxfu/15/ . I have attached a jsfiddle for sample code. I need the 7-9am columns to be bg gray down to the bottom of td.

Comment: Hi @disinfor https://jsfiddle.net/earlquartz47/ydn0wxfu/15/ . I have attached a jsfiddle for sample code. I need the 7-9am columns to be bg gray down to the bottom of td.

Comment: @AnthonyCuartero you're going to get a LOT more help if you put the code directly into your question, which I did. If you're using a framework, please update the post and say which one.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieve this by creating a `div` element inside the `th` and added a css class

```
.overlay-background{
   margin-top:-50px;
   margin-left:-20px;
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   width:100%;
   height:1000px;
   background-color: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.10);
   z-index: 2;
}
```

This is what it looks now.
[image]